# civimail sometimes stuck on running via Scheduled Jobs screen

Tags: civimail, mosaico, scheduled-job

We have set up a mailer using Mosaico and have set it to send immediately. There is no cron set up, so I have executed the "Send Scheduled Mailings" manually in the scheduled jobs settings.

If I use my test group (80 email addresses) the job starts and finises correctly.

If I send the mailer to the live list (120 email addresses) The job starts but never finishes and displays as running. The Successful Deliveries show as 0, but the unique opens are 1, so I'm unsure how many mailers have been sent out.

Some of the contacts in this group do not have email addresses, could this contribute to the issue?

We also have a mailer intended for 1500 email addresses that needs to go out.

The specs:
CiviCRM 5.43.2
Mosaico 2.8.1637146864
Wordpress 5.8.2
Php 7.4
Memory limit set to 1200 for now
We are still waiting on our hosting provider to be able to set up the Cron Job

Comment: The missing email addresses won't be contributing to the issue as they are filtered out during the list building phase - hence CiviCRM shows a count which is closer to the actual number its going to send. Do all emails sent have the same error i.e. 0 sends and 1 open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "Execute Now" from Scheduled Jobs isn't safe because your web server settings (in `php.ini`) will specify a maximum amount of time a page can run before it times out.  If you're executing a Scheduled Job, that job will fail.  It sounds like you're using shared hosting (which is not a great CiviCRM experience, speed-wise) so you may not be able to control the timeout, which is usually 30 seconds.

Assuming you can't change that to a much higher number, you'll need to wait for cron to be set up.

If you're absolutely desperate, you can go to **Administer menu » CiviMail » Mailer Settings** and set the *Mailer Batch Limit* to **80**.  This will prevent sending more than 80 emails per scheduled job, and you can manually press the "Execute Now" button once every 30 seconds for 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your feedback and will try your suggestion with the batch limit. Unfortunately, we are on a shared host and are having issues with the host provider. We can also not view our Apache logs at the moment. I did find the civicrm_mailing_event_delivered table in the database helpful when trying to see how many mails were sent out/delivered. Is there any other place where I could view logs/ get a hint on what is happening that you know of? Hopefully we get to move to a different host soon